# Field xx in xx service required a bean of type

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I'm getting the next error :

> Field ansRepo in com.myproject.services.ansService required a bean of type 'com.myproject.repositories.ansRepo' that could not be found.

I have a controller that has 4 services with autowired annotation :

```
@RestController
public class Controller {


@Autowired
private AnsService ansService

@Autowired
private QService QService;

@Autowired
private UService UService;
```

Each of those services has the @Service annotation :

```
@Service
public class ansService {

@Autowired
private AnsRepo ansrepo;
```

Each repository also has a @Repository annotation :

```
@Repository
public interface AnsRepo extends JpaRepository<Ans,Long> {
...
}
```

The error appears for the first autowired object in the controller, so it seems that the spring application can't find the autowired classes..

The structure of my project :

```
-com.myproject
----Main.java
----controllers
------------Controller.java
----entities
------------ans.java
----repositories
------------ansRepo.java
----services
------------ansService.java
```

My main :

```
package com.postmalone.Application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

 @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.myproject.controllers", 
 "com.myproject.services", "com.myproject.repositories", 
 "com.myproject.entities"})

 public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class,args);
```

I'm pretty sure that the issue is with the @SpringBootApplication annotation.I saw that there are many posts about this error but in my case I implemented already all the solutions that were provided.

What else should I check ?

### Update

I added in my Main app the @EnableJpaRepositories("com.myproject.repositories") annotation. Now I got the next error :

> Field ansRepo in com.postmalone.services.AnswService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The dependencies in my pom.xml file :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Why do I need to mention the @EnableJPARepostiory annotation when I have the @SpringBootApplication? And why I'm getting that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was just adding the next dependency in the pom.xml :

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

instead of :

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I noticed that you don't have a root package which should be shared for controllers, entities, repositories and services. 
In order to scan at the beginning of root package, simply add by following way:

```
 @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.myproject")
```

And rename the others packages by following way:

```
 com.myproject 
    >   Main.java
 com.myproject.controllers
    >   Controller.java
 com.myproject.entities
    >   Ans.java
 com.myproject.repositories
    >   AnsRepo.java
 com.myproject.services
    >   AnsService.java
```

Comment: does it matter where my main is located ? Update :: it didnt help

Comment: Are Application and Main classes different? can you post them?

Comment: No they are the same. My main class is located in the Application package. I posted the content of the main class

Comment: okay then remove Application package, why does it need within that package?

Comment: To be honest, I already tried it also and it didnt help. So right now, my main is outside of the application package. I update also the main post with that info.

Comment: Oh right!!1 it's missing add a root package which should be like these com.myproject.controllers, com.myproject.entities,com. myproject.repositories ... I noticed it right now xD I thought they were in this root package. update it will work..

Comment: When I try to rename the package name I see that the name is com.myproject.controllers. However, when it is displayed in the subtree I see the package name - controllers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186259/discussion-between-jonathan-johx-and-jeyj).

Comment: I added the next annotation in the spring runner app : @EnableJpaRepositories("com.myproject.repositories") and I got a different error message : Field ansRepo in com.myproject.services.AnsService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.